# Построение линий в mplfinance python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Всем доброго времени суток товарищи!
Весь день беюсь с валидатором, не пропускает данные, и не даёт отрисовать наклонную линию на графике:
Код

```
lines = [(f"{df.index[figure_points['t1']]}", figure_points['H1']), (f"{df.index[figure_points['t2']]}",
             figure_points['H2'])]
sell = mpf.make_addplot(sell, type="scatter", markersize=100, marker="v", panel=0, color="r")
buy = mpf.make_addplot(buy, type="scatter", markersize=100, marker="^", panel=0, color="g")
add.append(sell)
add.append(buy)
mpf.plot(df[-70:], style='yahoo', type="candle", title=f"Двойное дно CFXUSDT", figsize=(15, 8), figscale=10,
         addplot=add, hlines=dict(hlines=lines, colors="r", linestyle="-"))
```

Вот так выглядит код, который должен строить наклонную линию, но выдаёт следующую ошибку:

````
  File "D:\IT_Trading\Project-65\Binance.py", line 178, in <module>
    candles_data()
  File "D:\IT_Trading\Project-65\Binance.py", line 28, in candles_data
    double_bottom(df)
  File "D:\IT_Trading\Project-65\Binance.py", line 149, in double_bottom
    mpf.plot(df[-70:], style='yahoo', type="candle", title=f"Двойное дно CFXUSDT", figsize=(15, 8), figscale=10,
  File "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mplfinance\plotting.py", line 412, in plot
    config = _process_kwargs(kwargs, _valid_plot_kwargs())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mplfinance\_arg_validators.py", line 350, in _process_kwargs
    raise TypeError('kwarg "'+key+'" validator returned False for value: "'+str(value)+'"\n    '+v)
TypeError: kwarg "hlines" validator returned False for value: "{'hlines': [('2023-08-10 06:30:00', 0.1843), ('2023-08-10 17:00:00', 0.181)], 'colors': 'r', 'linestyle': '-'}"
    'Validator'   : lambda value: _hlines_validator(value) },```
````

Вот так выглядит график:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

по этим точкам нужно провести линию, но и как не могу этого сделать.
Подскажите пожалуйста, кто сталкивался с подобным, что нужно сделать ?

Comment: у вас в `hlines` в координаты должны передаваться только цены. для построения горизонтальных линий дата не нужна, что очевидно. Вам нужно использовать `alines`.

Comment: Пробовал все ```alines```, ```vlines```, ```tlines``` - у всех одинаковая ошибка

Comment: ну вот и приведите код с использованием `alines` и его ошибкой. потому что в вашем вопросе вы ставите перед собой одно задачу, а приводите другое решение.